# Oracle jdbc Wildfy problem Authentication lapse xxxxx ms

Tags: oracle, jdbc, wildfly

we have a problem with one of our Wildfly Application Server (v26) with a datasource connected to a Oracle 19 (19.16).
After restarting the appserver everythin is fine. Occasionally, after a few hours, CPU consumption of the java vm is very high an you can see in the server.log, following Exceptions:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: I/O-Fehler: Eine bestehende Verbindung wurde softwaregesteuert
durch den Hostcomputer abgebrochen, Authentication lapse 414217 ms.
    at deployment.ojdbc11.jar//oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.handleLogonIOException(T4CConnection.java:946)
    at deployment.ojdbc11.jar//oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:711)
    at deployment.ojdbc11.jar//oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:1089)
```

We've already checked memory_target of the db, because of https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/2524953_1.html, but it is set to 6G, which should be enough.

In alert.log we can find an hint, regarding time stalls:

```
2023-12-07T05:38:23.886428+01:00
Warning: VKTM detected a time stall. 
Time drifts can result in unexpected behavior such as time-outs.
```

In corresponding vtkm Logs you can see, the time differs 2-5 seconds occasionally.

The database an Wildfly are hosted on the same host.
We are using ojdbc11.jar from Oracle 21.5

Again, afterr restarting Wildfly everything ist fine for a few hours....

Does anyone has any idea what could be the problem?

Thanks in advance.
Zwaem

---

**EDIT**

Google Translate translates the German error message to English as:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: I/O error: An existing 
connection was software controlled aborted by the host computer, 
Authentication lapse 414217 ms.
```